# SSL seems to be not installed properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl

I have a certificate for a domain `example.com`. So, every request in my application (MVC 3) is being redirected to the `https://example.com`. But the problem is, I can see the padlock icon in the Firefox browser

[image]

but one second later it disappears and I see that there is no certificate ?

[image]

I have no clue what's going on, can somebody enlighten me ? The application is being hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "...which is run by (unknown)" message is just a message telling you that the certificate only verifies the web site name, not the owner. The message is not very clear and has been [reported as a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444980) to Mozilla.

The "Your connection to this site is only partially encrypted" message means that you're fetching at least *some* HTTP data as a part of your HTTPS page (*check your font/image/media links on the page*) and the data fetched via HTTP is not secure. A secure page should only link to HTTPS content, or someone listening to the connection may be able to the insecure communication and figure out what is done over the secure link. For example, if your cookies are not set as secure, they'll be sent over clear text too when fetching data from your site.

All in all, the SSL cert seems to be installed ok, but your page needs some updates to only link to secure content.